# How can I embed a font without giving the user the ability to download it?

Tags: php, css, apache, font-face

I know this is a bit contradicting seeing as the browser would have to download the font to render it but I was wondering if there is a way to host it where that it cannot be directly downloaded (or cached onto a user's computer for that matter).

A solution I came up with was to make a PHP script that hashes the current time to the second (adding a salt). If a particular variable in the GET request matches this hash then it will send out the header for the font's MIME type and then output the contents of the font file.

Then I would recreate the hash in the stylesheet and concatentate strings where that it would be a valid request to the PHP script.

That's the basic idea. I had it working. But there were two flaws in this:

1. If the browser requests the font on a different second, the PHP script would fail to match the hashes up, therefore, would output nothing thus the font would be the backup font (or the default font if none were provided)
2. If someone were quick enough, he/she could still download the font directly if he/she requested it on the same second (granted this would probably have to be a script that would do this.

Also does the browser cache the font anywhere (not that the caching would help since the hash in the URI would practically always be different).

EDIT: Are there any `$_SERVER` variables that I could utilize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers say, it's very difficult (impossible) against someone that really wants to download it. There is pretty much always a way. However, to give you some ideas, [this article](http://blog.typekit.com/2009/07/21/serving-and-protecting-fonts-on-the-web/) describes how Typekit handles the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the font to be useable by the browser for displaying your page, you MUST allow it be downloaded somehow. Once it's put onto the wire and sent to the browser, it is utterly out of your hands as to what the user will do with it.

You can only make it a bit harder to retrieve, and a knowledgeable user will bypass anything you do with trivial ease.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more difficult, as your solution does, however if your goal is to protect your font IP, it simply cannot be downloadable by a browser. You cannot control what the browser does no matter how hard you try, against a dedicated adversary.

What you can do though, perhaps, is provide server-side code to generate an image using your font, and serve that image instead. I assume you're not trying to prevent the user from seeing the rendering of this font, just from using the font directly?

Comment: I'd like the text to be search engine friendly so unfortunately the image solution isn't ideal. Thought about it for a second, though. :/

Comment: You can add the text in your <img> element, within an `alt` attribute -- see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp for some details. Alternatively you can include a hidden <div> with the content, sans-font.

Comment: Yes, but if the text is lengthy, it would be one heck of an image to download/generate.